# In general $\overline{U_\epsilon(x)}=K_\epsilon(x)$ false

Tags: general-topology, inequality

First of all let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. We know that the set $K_\epsilon(x)=\{y\in M \mid  d(x,y)\le\epsilon\}$ for arbitrary $x\in M$ and $\epsilon>0$ is closed and $\overline{U_\epsilon(x)}\subseteq K_\epsilon(x)$

In $\mathbb R^n$ with the Euclidean metric we have an equality but in general it is false.

Now my question: What does this inequality has to do with $M:= S^1\cup\{(x_1,0)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid 0\le x_1\le 1\}$ with the constraint of the euclidean metric and the corresponding spheres with radius 1 ?

Here $K_\epsilon(x)=\{y\in M \mid  d(x,y)\le\epsilon\}$ and  $U_\epsilon(x)=\{y\in M \mid  d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$

Comment: What is $U_\epsilon(x)$?

Comment: Did you mean $\leq$ in the definition of $K_\epsilon(x)$ as opposed to $<$?  Cause what you have written as $K_\epsilon(x)$ looks to me like the definition of an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$, which is of course open.

Comment: Yes, $U_\epsilon(x)=\{y\in M | d(x,y<\epsilon)\}$ and $K_\epsilon(x)=\{y\in M | d(x,y)\le\epsilon\}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila No. $U$ is open, $K$ is the closure of $U$. Seems the OP is wondering about **relative** closures, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ADD** In your case, let $$K_1(0)=\{x\in M:d(x,0)\leq 1\}$$ Then $K_1(0)$ is all of $M$. On the other hand, $$U_1(0)=\{x\in M:d(x,0)<1\}=\{(x,0):0<x<1\}$$ and the closure of $U_1(0)$ in $M$, that is, relative to $M$, is $$\overline{U_1(0)}_M=\{(x,0):0\leq x\leq 1\}$$

---

It seems you're wondering about relative closures in metric spaces. Suppose we're working in a metric space $(X,\rho)$. Fix some subset $E$ of $X$. Then we say $F\subseteq E$ is relatively open in $E$, or open relative to $E$, or $E$-open if $F=E\cap O$ for $O$ open in $X$. We analogously say $K$ is closed relative to $E$ if $K=E\cap L$ for some closed $L$ in $X$.

With this in mind, we can talk about relative closures and relative interiors of sets. In particular fixing a subset $E$ of $X$, we define the closure of $F\subseteq E$ as $$\operatorname{cl}_E F=\bigcap\mathscr C$$

where $\mathscr C$ is the collection of all relatively closed sets in $E$ that contain $F$. You can then see that $$\operatorname{cl}_E F=E\cap\operatorname{cl}  F$$

We can do the same for $\operatorname{int}_E F$. Thus, in general you'll have that

$$\operatorname{cl}_E F\subseteq \operatorname{cl}  F$$

$$\operatorname{int}_E F\supseteq \operatorname{int}  F$$
You can even do this for nested subsets $M\subseteq N\subseteq X$ for $X$ a topological space. In such case we will have for $F\subseteq M\subseteq N$

$$\operatorname{cl}_M F\subseteq \operatorname{cl}_N  F$$

$$\operatorname{int}_M F\supseteq \operatorname{int}_N  F$$

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain me where the difference is between $cl_E F$ and $cl F$ ? because I define the closure of $E$ as $\bar{E}:=\bigcap_{E\subseteq F, F closed}F$

Comment: @Babla If you read what I wrote carefully, you'll see that $\operatorname{cl}_E F$ is the "relative" closure, that is, we consider the intersection over all relatively closed sets that contain $F$. On the other hand, $\operatorname{cl} F$ is the usual closure, taken over usual closed sets.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the closure of $[0,1)\times\{0\}$ (the open unit ball in $M$) is $[0,1]\times\{0\}$, but the closed unit ball is all of $M$

Comment: Should the first set be $(0,1)\times \{0\}$?